# How to search data in combination of field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a student table with first_name and last_name. when i apply the search on first name or last name it give me the correct record but when i search with complete name it does not return any thing. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
  `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid`, 
  `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name` AS `fname` 
FROM 
  `student_personal_info` 
WHERE 
 ((spi_first_name like '%test developer%') OR (spi_last_name like '%test developer%') 
ORDER BY 
 `spi_first_name` ASC
```

Is there any way to make it searchable with both field combination.

It will give record in case we enter first name .middle name and last name but don't fetch in case of firstname and last name not middle name.

```
SELECT `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid` , `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name` AS `fname`
FROM `student_personal_info`
WHERE (
spi_scholar_no LIKE '%amir hussain khan%'
)
OR (
CONCAT( spi_first_name, ' ', spi_middle_name, ' ', spi_last_name ) LIKE '%amir hussain khan%'
```

I have also try this but its working for exact match only.

```
SELECT `student_parents_info`.`spri_spi_id` AS `sid`
FROM `student_parents_info`
WHERE (MATCH (spri_first_name, spri_middle_name, spri_last_name) AGAINST ('Pramod Kumar Sharma*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) )
ORDER BY `spri_first_name` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Please give any other suggestions.

Comment: for complete name you need to use and not or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching using concat()..

```
SELECT `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid` , `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name`    AS `fname`
FROM `student_personal_info`
  WHERE CONCAT( spi_first_name, ' ', spi_middle_name, ' ', spi_last_name ) LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY `spi_first_name` ASC
```

It always works for me .

Comment: What if first name is `test` and second in `tester` it will not match rite ?

Comment: @new_developer How i can manage this in case of middle name because some user have middle name and some not. can you please give me any solution

Comment: @PrasanthBendra It will not match either because we are searching for 'test developer' – new_developer

Comment: @Pramod You mean you want to search with combination of three fields  ?

Comment: @new_developer yeah i want to search with 3 fields but the problem is that some may have or may not have middle name.

Comment: @Pramod Thats not a problem.... include third fild also in search like CONCAT(spi_first_name,' ',middle_name," ",spi_last_name) like '%test develope%' .. it should work .. whether user has middle name or not it will not make any difference

Comment: @new_developer its not working well whith middle name, may be because some student don't have middle name ...i have updated my question

Comment: @Pramod I have seen it try ... it without the space like CONCAT(spi_first_name,'',middle_name,"",spi_last_name) like '%testdevelope%' .   tell me does it make any difference .. ? We should not be concerned about the spaces as we are jst using it for searching and not to display anything.

Comment: @new_developer its not working in this way , search string should in the same order as it concatenation but in this middle name optional. may be look at some other option..whats your take on this bro

Comment: @Pramod ... I always use it in this way and it works .. anyhow I will definately update you if I get any other option..

Comment: @Pramod cannt find anything better .. well can you send me structure of your table with dummy data anyhow ... ? only then I can see it

Comment: @new_developeryour email id plx

Comment: @Pramod developerstack@gmail.com

Comment: @Pramod check my edited answer .. it is working perfectly .. whether middle name is there or not .. It will search for test in all three names 'middle name', 'first name',''last name' try it

Comment: @new_developer yeah its looking like it will work... let me check this in different cases

Comment: @new_developer Boss Its now working  for full like '%Pramod Kumar Sharma%' :(

Comment: @Pramod what is you search only for '%Pramod%'

Comment: @new_developer actually its confusing sometime user can search  '%Pramod%' , '%Pramod Kumar%' ,'%Pramod Sharma%', '%Pramod Kumar Sharma%' the search should give result in any case and sorry for bothering you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid`, `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name` AS `fname` 
FROM `student_personal_info`
WHERE 
    ((spi_first_name like '%amir khan%') OR (spi_last_name like '%test develope%'))
ORDER BY `spi_first_name` ASC
```

you are missing ')'

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive a full name to perform the search with? or do you always get 2 separate (first and last name)?

If you get one full name string, change your query to concatenate first and last name, and use

```
GROUP BY HAVING(full_name LIKE %search_term%)
```

if you get two separate strings, just change your OR to AND between the first and last name LIKE tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CONCAT:

```
SELECT
  `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid`,
  `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name` AS `fname`
FROM
  `student_personal_info`
WHERE 
  CONCAT(spi_first_name, ' ', spi_last_name) LIKE '%test develope%'
ORDER BY
 `spi_first_name` ASC
```

Comment: What if first name is `test` and second in `tester` it will not match rite ?

Answer (score 0):

Split your `test develope` to `test` and `develope` using php, then write query like this :

```
$first = 'test';
$last  = 'develope';

$query = "SELECT `student_personal_info`.`spi_id` AS `sid`, `student_personal_info`.`spi_first_name` AS `fname` FROM `student_personal_info` WHERE 
(spi_first_name like '%".$first."%') OR (spi_last_name like '%".$last."%') 
ORDER BY `spi_first_name` ASC";
```

If you have more than two words, Split the words and create the dynamic `where` query.